# Gradle can't resolve references from another module

Tags: gradle, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

I have a project with the following modules:

- App
- Device

App depends on device. Device contains a NetworkComponent class that app references. More specifically:

```
package com.some.package.ui.login;

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.some.package.R
import com.some.package.device.network.NetworkComponent
import com.some.package.ui.terms.TermsActivity

class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity(),
        LoginViewModel.Navigator {

    val loginViewModel by lazy { LoginViewModel(this, NetworkComponent()) }
```

Everything resolves fine in Android Studio. Yet when I attempt to build the project, I encounter a build error:

```
e: /Users/android/some-app-android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/some/package/ui/login/LoginActivity.kt: (7, 27): Unresolved reference: network
e: /Users/android/some-app-android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/some/package/ui/login/LoginActivity.kt: (13, 55): Unresolved reference: NetworkComponent
[KOTLIN] deleting /Users/android/some-app-android/app/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug on error
[KOTLIN] deleting /Users/android/some-app-android/app/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug on error
:app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
```

This is what NetworkComponent looks like:

```
package com.some.package.device.network

import com.some.package.domain.datasources.CodeValidator
import retrofit2.Retrofit


class NetworkComponent : CodeValidator {

    val codeValidator: CodeValidatorApi

    init {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("www.test.com")
                .build()

        codeValidator = retrofit.create(CodeValidatorApi::class.java)
    }

    override fun validate(code: String) = codeValidator.validate(code)
}
```

Here are the build files:

Top:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'
    ext.android_tools = '3.0.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$android_tools"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

App:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

//apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

// Manifest version information
def versionMajor = 0
def versionMinor = 0
def versionPatch = 1

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.some.package"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode versionMajor * 10000 + versionMinor * 100 + versionPatch
        versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
//            applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
            resValue "string", "application_name", "TEST APP Debug"
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            resValue "string", "application_name", "TEST APP"
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        debug.java.srcDirs += 'src/debug/kotlin'
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor' // butterknife
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://github.com/uPhyca/stetho-realm/raw/master/maven-repo' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':device')
    implementation project(':data')
    implementation project(':domain')

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.0'
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$android_tools"

    // Logging
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.1'

    // Unit tests
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
//    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.11.0'
//    testImplementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'

//    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.1'
//    releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.1'
//    testImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.1'



    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.1.0'

    debugImplementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.4.1'
    debugImplementation 'com.uphyca:stetho_realm:2.0.0'
//    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
//        transitive = true;
//    }
}
```

Device:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(':domain')

    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'

    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.1.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I'm not quite sure how this can happen. I tried downgrading the gradle plugin to 2.3.3, but no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Might be caused somehow by the fact that `NetworkComponent` implements `CodeValidator`. Is `CodeValidator` public?

Comment: @Egor Yes. It's in another module. I commented out CodeValidator so that NetworkComponent does not implement it but the result is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out I was missing this key line in my device module build file:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

Thanks to this answer for the clue https://stackoverflow.com/a/31671696/918585