# 'Unresolved reference' errors for android library module referenced in app module

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I have problems referencing my android library modules in my projects. Beside the main app module I use to have an android library module with either util stuff or as data module. I reference it in app module like that:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(":data")
}
```

When I build the project, it´s giving me lot of error messages `'Unresolved reference: ...'` for all stuff that I reference in the app module to the android library module. But the IDE itself doesn´t have a problem, Intelligent finds all classes, interfaces etc., imports are fine, nothing is red. The android library module itself builds and creates `aar-file` in the output. It´s the `compileDebugKotlin` task that fails

Any general idea what may be related to that?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Found the problem, my android library module was missing the kotlin configuration:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlinVersion:<version>"
}
```

Although I used kotlin .kt files in it, it could build without and also

`Tools -> Kotlin -> 'Configure Kotlin in projects'`

had told me **'All modules with Kotlin files are configured'**

Comment: I'm having the same issue except.. my project is not missing any dependencies.. I wish this error was more descriptive.

Comment: That was a nasty and annoying thing to debug. Android Studio should make this less painful.

Comment: Wow. This really helped. Excellent find!

Comment: a year and a half later and they haven't fixed this. google please throw a real error. it's not cool when the IDE tells you everything is cool.

Answer (score 19):

Your module's `build.gradle` file should have:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 15):

In my case It was `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'`,

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

and also added it on build.gradle

```
androidExtensions {
  experimental = true
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If it is a `kotlin` module make sure to add in its `build.gradle` file

`apply plugin: 'kotlin'`

Comment: This one is useful if it is a general purpose library!

Comment: This one fixed the problem for me. In my case, I had a Kotlin module without Android dependencies for a general-purpose library. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I was using CoroutineWorkers and in my case I had to add **work-runtime-ktx** dependency to use it

```
implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.4.0"
```