# Android Error:Unresolved reference: utils

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Please help me to resolve this *Unresolved Reference* errors

Before every run I have to

**Clean Build, Rebuild and Then Install** to my device

Please help me to save my time by rebuild again and again.

***This issue is on android studio 3.6.2 and Koltlin version 1.3.61***

[image: No error in this line]

[image: But here showing]

Comment: File->invalidate caches/restart

Comment: i try this already. But before every run i have to rebuild

Comment: Attach your code and the error line please

Comment: no error but due to some kotlin extensions, i can't able to run my app continuously

Comment: Please check if this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49124353/unresolved-reference-errors-for-android-library-module-referenced-in-app-modul

Comment: already added this implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem of the single package named as **utils** and i resolved this issue by **importing all files** of this package into any **new package**. It is a Project level problem with Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps

> File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate and restart

Comment: Send me the page error and the files of your project

Comment: okok first go to build -> clean project then check first where the utils file is, then clean the imports of utils and try to import with the actions alt + enter, this happens in some computers with the new android studio.